How to start `robot_localization`
I'm currently working on a multi-agent navigation task. I need to use robot_localization for fusing different odometry data. I wrote a function to generate multiple robot_localization nodes:
def robot_localization_node_gen(i, j):
    print(f"i = {i}, j= {j}")
    robot1 = 'robot' + str(i)
    robot2 = 'robot' + str(j)
    odom_parent = '/'.join([robot1, 'odom'])
    odom_child = '/'.join([robot2, 'odom'])
    wheel_rel_odom_topic = '_'.join(['wheel_rel_odom', str(robot1), str(robot2)])
    point_odom_topic = '_'.join(['pointlk_reg', str(robot1), str(robot2)])

    robot_localization_node = Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        name='_'.join(['ekf_filter_node', str(i), str(j)]),
        namespace='',
        output='screen',
        parameters= [{'publish_tf': False,
                      'odom_frame': odom_child,
                      'base_link_frame': odom_parent,
                      'world_frame': odom_child,
                      'odom0': wheel_rel_odom_topic,
                      'odom0_config': [False,  False,  False,
                                        False, False, False,
                                        True, True, False,
                                        False, False, True,
                                        False, False, False],
                    'odom0_twist_rejection_threshold': 1.0,
                    'odom1': point_odom_topic,
                    'odom1_config': [True,  True,  False,
                                     False, False, True,
                                    False, False, False,
                                    False, False, False,
                                    False, False, False],
                    'odom1_pose_rejection_threshold': 5.0}],
    )
    return robot_localization_node

which fuses odometry from wheel odometry and pointcloud registration. However, this node now outputs nothing. The odometry sources are both working properly. They publishes odometry on frame odom_parent -> odom_child. So I don't understand why this node has no output. Should I use /set_pose as initial, or is there any mistake in my config? Thanks a lot!

Please post a sample message from each sensor input.
